# Combine same columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have two dataframes

First dataframe, df1

```
    UserMasterId    Status  Count
  0 1296.0               5  5
  1 1316.0               5  9
  2 1325.0               5  14
  3 1332.0               5  5
  4 1337.0               5  44
  5 1342.0               5  2
  6 1344.0               5  18
```

Second dataframe, df2

```
    UserMasterId    Status  Count
  0 1325.0               0  2
  1 1332.0               0  1
  2 1337.0               0  1
  3 1342.0               0  3
  4 1344.0               0  1
```

Here we have same ID in both dataframes..

When I use **Concat**,

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, sort=True)
result
```

The output I get is,

```
    UserMasterId    Status  Count   UserMasterId    Status  Count
0   1296.0               5      5         1325.0       0.0    2.0
1   1316.0               5      9         1332.0       0.0    1.0
2   1325.0               5     14         1337.0       0.0    1.0
3   1332.0               5      5         1342.0       0.0    3.0
4   1337.0               5     44         1344.0       0.0    1.0
5   1342.0               5      2            NaN       NaN    NaN
6   1344.0               5     18            NaN       NaN    NaN
```

When i use **Merge**,

```
result = pd.merge(df1,df2[['UserMasterId', 'Count','Status']],on='UserMasterId')
result.head()
```

The output is,

```
    UserMasterId    Status_x    Count_x Count_y Status_y
0         1325.0           5         14      2         0
1         1332.0           5          5      1         0
2         1337.0           5         44      1         0
3         1342.0           5          2      3         0
4         1344.0           5         18      1         0
```

This removes the ID that is not common in df1 & df2.

I don't want to remove the ID that is not common to both dataframes.
I want the output like this,

```
UserMasterId    Status_x    Count_x Count_y Status_y
0     1296.0           5          5      NA       NA
1     1316.0           5          9      NA       NA
2     1325.0           5         14      2         0
3     1332.0           5          5      1         0
4     1337.0           5         44      1         0
5     1342.0           5          2      3         0
6     1344.0           5         18      1         0
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on='UserMasterId')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using merge with an outer join should do it was well, right? I did not test it however

```
result = pd.merge(df1,df2[['UserMasterId', 'Count','Status']],on='UserMasterId', how='outer')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the method append :

```
df3 = df1.append(df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`pd.concat` is the solution here, but you need to add the `ignore_index` parameter and not set `axis` to `1`, as such:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 1], 'b': [2, 3]})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b': [4, 5], 'a': [5, 6]})
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
   a  b
0  0  2
1  1  3
2  5  4
3  6  5
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `how='outer'`

```
result = pd.merge(df1,df2[['UserMasterId', 'Count','Status']],on='UserMasterId', how='outer')
print(result)

   UserMasterId  Status_x  Count_x  Count_y  Status_y
0        1296.0         5        5      NaN       NaN
1        1316.0         5        9      NaN       NaN
2        1325.0         5       14      2.0       0.0
3        1332.0         5        5      1.0       0.0
4        1337.0         5       44      1.0       0.0
5        1342.0         5        2      3.0       0.0
6        1344.0         5       18      1.0       0.0
```